# css on hover change lid up stars

Tags: css

Hey all i have this piece of css which allows me to show stars from 0 till 5. I can set the class to determine how many stars need to be lid up. How can i change the value on hover. I have tryed adding the :hover value but this gives me unexpected results.

I just added the hover class as the after class as the after effect is what i am trying to accomplish but then dynamicly. When doing this the stars are hovered at the top of the page making the original gray stars invisible and it doesnt reflect the amount of stars i hovered. i am not that skilled in css so any help would be appriciated

```
<style>
        .stars{
            display:block;
            width:79px;
            background-position:0 -16px;
            position:relative;

            text-indent:100%;
            white-space:nowrap;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .stars,
        .stars:hover,
        .stars:after{
            height:16px;
            background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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);

        }
        .stars:after,.stars:hover{
            content:"";
            background-position:0 0;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
        }

        .s-0:after      { width: 0  ; }
        .s-05:after   { width: 8px; }
        .s-1:after      { width:16px; }
        .s-15:after   { width:24px; }
        .s-2:after      { width:32px; }
        .s-25:after   { width:40px; }
        .s-3:after      { width:48px; }
        .s-35:after   { width:56px; }
        .s-4:after      { width:64px; }
        .s-45:after   { width:72px; }
        .s-5:after      { width:80px; }


 .s-0:hover      { width: 0  ; }
        .s-05:hover   { width: 8px; }
        .s-1:hover      { width:16px; }
        .s-15:hover   { width:24px; }
        .s-2:hover      { width:32px; }
        .s-25:hover   { width:40px; }
        .s-3:hover      { width:48px; }
        .s-35:hover   { width:56px; }
        .s-4:hover      { width:64px; }
        .s-45:hover   { width:72px; }
        .s-5:hover      { width:80px; }

</style>



  <a href='#' > <span class="col-sm-6 stars s-0" align="center"></span></a>
```

Comment: Can you include the `:hover` styles you tried, and explain *how* the results were unexpected? Without seeing the problematic code, it's difficult to provide a solution.

Comment: you only need to reset bg position on :hover , no ?

Comment: You can't change styles depending on cursor position only on one element (in pure CSS). You need to make one element per star. And also using JavaScript would be better here

Comment: well i would like to use javascript just not sure how to change the element. would that be an onchange event or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Full stars

```js
$('.js-stars *').on('click', function(event) {
  var count = $(this).data('stars');
  alert(count + ' star(s) selected');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.stars-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.stars {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0 -16px;
}
.stars:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.stars--one {
  width: 16px;
}
.stars--two {
  width: 32px;
}
.stars--three {
  width: 48px;
}
.stars--four {
  width: 64px;
}
.stars--five {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars-wrapper js-stars">
  <span class="stars stars--five" data-stars="1">
<span class="stars stars--four" data-stars="2">
<span class="stars stars--three" data-stars="3">
<span class="stars stars--two" data-stars="4">
<span class="stars stars--one" data-stars="5">
</span>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I use JavaScript here to detect a count of selected stars. 
Stars are highlighted by pure CSS.

### Soft stars selection

```js
$('.stars').on('mouseover mousemove', function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  $(this).find('.stars__selection').width(x);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).find('.stars__selection').width(0);
}).on('click', function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  $(this).find('.stars__selection').width(x);
  var width = $(this).width();
  var result = Math.round(x / width * 100); // in percent
  alert(result + '% selected');
});
```

```css
.stars,
.stars__selection {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) 0 -16px;
}
.stars__selection {
  width: 0;
  background-position: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars">
  <div class="stars__selection"></div>
</div>
```

This solution won't work without JavaScript.
There is a problem: it's hard to select 100% or 0% :)

Comment: half stars dont work though is it possible to add this to the script? tryed adding the classes but then i just get half stars

Comment: Hey Cool! Thanks. I think i will be able to work with this :) i can just round the value to half stars or full stars

Comment: Still got some issues which i cant seem to shake :(. Once an option is selected i want it to stay lid up. I managed to achieve this by adding another mouseout event inside the onclick event. But this make the hover a little bit buggie and when hovering it sets a new value. Basicly i need it to remember the value when on click is used. So then the value needs to be set. When you hover over it again without clicking it needs to go back to the set value but when clicking on a new value the new value needs to be set. Is this doable with this function?

Comment: @Wouter you just need to store the value inside the `onclick` event and set the `.stars__selection` width to the stored value on `mouseout` event. I'd use data attributes for this purpose. Don't need add more event listeners :) Let me know if you need an example of code